# looking for usage example of dataflow client for c# (nuget) - running job by template

Tags: c#, api, google-cloud-dataflow, nuget-package

I have a working code to load data to bigtable by dataflow-template by http request.I want to change it to work with the nuget client library for c#, but I can find any example, and the [reference](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Dataflow.v1b3/latest/api/Google.Apis.Dataflow.v1b3.html) is not so helpfull... can someone give me any reference how should I use this client?

my existing code is like that

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            var obj = new requestFormat
            {
                jobName = fileName,
                parameters = new parameters
                {
                    bigtableInstanceId = "ariel",
                    bigtableProjectId = cloudProjectId,
                    bigtableTableId = "ariel",
                    inputFilePattern = $"gs://{bucketName}/{fileName}.avro"
                }
            };


            var objStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

            var content = new StringContent(objStr, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = client.PostAsync("https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/proj/templates:launch?gcsPath=gs://dataflow-templates/latest/GCS_Avro_to_Cloud_Bigtable", content).Result;

            var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            Console.WriteLine(responseString);

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I succeeded by

```
        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault();
        credential = credential.CreateScoped(new List<string>() { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute" });
        var dataflowService = new DataflowService(new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential
        });

        var launchTemplateParameters = new LaunchTemplateParameters();
        launchTemplateParameters.JobName = fileName; 
        launchTemplateParameters.Parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
            { "bigtableInstanceId", "arielh" },
            { "bigtableProjectId", cloudProjectId },
            { "bigtableTableId", "ariel" },
            { "inputFilePattern", $"gs://{bucketName}/{fileName}.avro" }
        };
        var locationResources = dataflowService.Projects.Locations;
        var launchRequest = locationResources.Templates.Launch(launchTemplateParameters, cloudProjectId, location);
        launchRequest.GcsPath = "gs://dataflow-templates/latest/GCS_Avro_to_Cloud_Bigtable";
        var launchTemplateResponse = launchRequest.Execute();
        var jobId = launchTemplateResponse.Job.Id;
        var getRequest = locationResources.Jobs.Get(cloudProjectId, location, jobId);
        var timer = new Timer(2000);
        timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var jobStatus = getRequest.Execute();
            var currentState = jobStatus.CurrentState;
            if (currentState != "JOB_STATE_STOPPED" && currentState != "JOB_STATE_RUNNING")
            {
                if (currentState == "JOB_STATE_DONE")
                {
                    timer.Stop();
                    Console.WriteLine("job done");
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception($"job {jobId} not finished successfully. current state: {currentState}");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("job is running");
            }
        };
```